# how to connect to a mySQL instance remotely?

Tags: c#, mysql, ssh

I have written a fantastic c# app that makes use of a connection to a mySQL database. While the app was under development, I simply ran an instance of mySQL server on my local machine and the c# app would connect locally. Now it is time to transfer the database onto a remotely located server that is also running an instance of mySQL server.

I was able to transfer the entire database over to the new server PC, now I am trying to connect remotely but am running into multiple issues. One issue being that (as per a test from http://www.portcheckers.com/) port 3306 is blocked. (according to pertcheckers, the ONLY open port is port 22 (ssh))

I am not very good with mySQL but am trying to figure out how to make the remote connection. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
mysql -h ***-SRVR1 -u root -p ****
```

this gives the error:

```
Acess denied for user 'OBDC'@'192.168.1.***
```

Since portcheckers said that only port 22 was open, I tried using mySQL workbench to make the connection using the "TCIP SSH" option to no avail.

Can anyone help me set up this connection? I have remote desktop access to the server PC and I am on my local machine that I want to make the connection from.

Also, I have not granted remote acess yet. I am trying that now by going onto the remote PC and running:

```
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

to see if that helps

Comment: if you put mysql onto port 22, then you wouldn't be able to ssh into the server anymore. don't do that. open up port 3306, which mysql's standard tcp port.

Comment: MySQL workbench does support Connection through Standard TCP/IP over SSH. you don't need extra software to create tunnel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a really bad idea to open up port 3306 for remote access. It's too dangerous.

You have three options:

1. Get your client to connect via ssh on port 22, and then tunnel the MySQL connection.
2. Put the two machines on the same VPN, so that they appear to have a local connection even though they're distant.
3. Write some sort of web service to arbitrate between the two, and field database connections.

The third is complex and heavy duty, and not really something you want to consider unless it's a big application and you have a lot of resources. I'd start with the first, and then move to the second if you want something a bit more solid and flexible.

To get option 1 up and running, you shouldn't have to install anything extra on the server. See if you can ssh to the remote machine (either use putty from the client end, if you're using Windows, or `ssh` from the client command line if you're on Linux). If you can log on, you'll then need to look in the documentation for port forwarding: basically you need to forward some local port (e.g., 8306) to port 3306 on the remote end. Once you've done that, you leave `ssh` running, and tell your client application to connect to `localhost:8306`. It will magically forward everything (encrypted) down the ssh tunnel, and pass it to port 3306 (the MySQL server) at the far end.

Comment: I would love to do option #1. Is there any way someone can help me accomplish this? Is there some type of connection string I will need? I would like to avoid installing any 3-rd party software like putty, since I do not have full admin rights on the remote server.

Comment: @JohnAugust I've edited the answer to give a little more detail.

Comment: @JohnAugust Please do click the tick to select the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: @chiastic-security, you might need to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost when forwarding mysql port-3306.